# Node and Mongo forEach loop

Tags: node.js, mongodb, foreach

l have a forEach loop that is iterating through my Json object of users to check if a certain users exists and if that user does not exist it must save the user but the problem l am having with the forEach is that is keeps on looping and the loop end up being infinite. l have noticed that the Break function does not work on the forEach loop. Does anyone have an idea of what l can do or use to break out of the forEach loop after it loops once.

Comment: Can you post your code, please?

Comment: no worries l solved it, but thanks